# Proper way to check if a list contains anything (or is not empty)

Tags: java, arrays, list

Is `if (list != null) { ... }` a proper way to check if a list has any element in it? I do not want to use `list.contains("")` for a specific element. Only to check if it is empty or not. 
`list.isEmpty()` checks if a list is empty. What is the ideal opposite of it for Java?

Comment: _"list.isEmpty() checks if a list is empty. What is the ideal opposite of it for java?"_  `!list.isEmpty()` ?`

Comment: list != null would be checking if the list has been intialized

Comment: One should try to teach oneself the basics of the language first: the question here is not about lists, but about how to negate a boolean...

Comment: Please, to know if a list not null and is empty just do !list.isEmpty()

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check whether list is intiialized or not then use the null check as mentioned here:

```
if( list != null)
```

To check whether list is non null and does not contains any element then add `isEmpty` method check also

```
if( list != null && !list.isEmpty())
```

Comment: does list.isEmpty() method work if list has not been initialised?

Answer (score 1):

list != null would check if the list been initialized or not.
However list.isEmpty() would check if it contains any element or not.

```
!list.isEmpty()  should work for you.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>() 
l.isEmpty() ; // checks whether there are any elements in the list l. You will get NullPointerException if l is null
if(l!=null)  // checks whether l is a reference to a object or not. i.e, has l been initialized?
```

Comment: @theDownVoter.. I didnt ask you to undo your downvote.. I am asking the reason for downvoting.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
  doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is if (list != null) { ... } a proper way to check if a list has any
>   element in it?

No. This checks if the `list` object is initialized or not. I can still initialize `list` with an empty list implementation i.e `list = new ArrayList();`

> I do not want to use list.contains("") for a specific element.

Nor should you. This would return true if and element existed that was an empty String i.e.

```
list.add("");
list.consains("");   //true
list.size();    // 1
```

> Only to check if it is empty or not.  list.isEmpty() checks if a list
>   is empty. What is the ideal opposite of it for Java?

`list.isEmpty()` returns a boolean. As with any boolean, you an apply the ! operator to flip it. i.e.

```
!true;   //false 
!list.isEmpty(); //checks if it is NOT empty
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(Collection obj)` from [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty(java.util.Collection)) 
Using this it would check if the list is null as well as not empty.

Answer (score -3):

um.  !list.isEmpty()?  You're really just asking how to check if a list is not empty?

Comment: i think the idea is that positive booleans are easier to read.